# sequelize (and sequelize-cli) queryInterface.createTable on PostgreSQL with PK id of type UUID with defaultValue: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUIDV4 failure

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

Do sequelize support using UUID type id that is auto generated in postgreSQL dialect?
Very surprised about CREATE TABLE sql generated, which does not seem to be correct for postgreSQL dialect.

sequelize queryInterface.createTable via queryGenerator.createTableQuery on PostgreSQL with PK id of type UUID with defaultValue: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUIDV4 does NOT seem to create proper CREATE TABLE that will create default UUID values for id when id value is not provided.

Below call of queryInterface.createTable

```
await queryInterface.createTable(
  // 'tableName'
  'User2s', 
  // 'attributes'
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
//    autoIncrement: true,  // with this "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate" fails with 'ERROR syntax error at or near "SERIAL"' for type UUID. So not using this. This would work if id type was INTEGER (without setting 'defaultValue')
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,  
//    defaultValue: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUIDV4,  // tried this instead of above too
//    defaultValue: require('sequelize').UUIDV4, // tried this instead of above too
      primaryKey: true,
      type: Sequelize.UUID
    },
    firstName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    lastName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    }
  },
  // 'options'
  {schema: process.env.DB_POSTGRESQL_SCHEMA_NAME}
);
```

creates below SQL (with dialect set as postgreSQL);

```
CREATE TABLE exp15c."User2s"
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    "firstName" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "lastName" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "User2s_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

But above generated CREATE TABLE for postgreSQL probably should had been;

```
CREATE TABLE exp15c."User2s"
(
    id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "firstName" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "lastName" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "User2s_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

When I look at documents at;
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/9f950cbcbdd659d559496b77c40e0f827b108561/docs/manual/core-concepts/model-basics.md
UUIDs
For UUIDs, use DataTypes.UUID. It becomes the UUID data type for PostgreSQL and SQLite, and CHAR(36) for MySQL. Sequelize can generate UUIDs automatically for these fields, simply use Sequelize.UUIDV1 or Sequelize.UUIDV4 as the default value:

```
{
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4 // Or Sequelize.UUIDV1
}
```

It basically says, my above usage is correct.

When I look at sequelize source code, I see at;
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/9f950cbcbdd659d559496b77c40e0f827b108561/lib/utils.js

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid').v4;
function toDefaultValue(value, dialect) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    const tmp = value();
    if (tmp instanceof DataTypes.ABSTRACT) {
      return tmp.toSql();
    }
    return tmp;
  }
  if (value instanceof DataTypes.UUIDV1) {
    return uuidv1();
  }
  if (value instanceof DataTypes.UUIDV4) {
    return uuidv4();
  }
  if (value instanceof DataTypes.NOW) {
    return now(dialect);
  }
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.slice();
  }
  if (_.isPlainObject(value)) {
    return { ...value };
  }
  return value;
}
exports.toDefaultValue = toDefaultValue;
```

and above method being used in
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/9f950cbcbdd659d559496b77c40e0f827b108561/lib/model.js
_initValues(values, options) {
but not sure if it really applies to my use case.

The above generated CREATE TABLE sql executes and creates the table, but will not work when we try to INSERT without id value, which is what I am trying to do.

To be very detailed;
I am using sequelize via sequelize-cli commands like below;
0) make sure your postgreSQL DB has new schema 'exp15c'
initialize sequelize directories and files
npx sequelize-cli init

1. create model and migrations
   npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User2 --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string
   which creates model as;

   'use strict';
   const {
   Model
   } = require('sequelize');
   module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   class User2 extends Model {
   static associate(models) {
   // define association here
   }
   };
   User2.init({
   firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
   lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
   email: DataTypes.STRING
   }, {
   sequelize,
   modelName: 'User2',
   });
   return User2;
   }
2. Manually update generated migration file to have above code in it's "up"

   'use strict';
   module.exports = {
   up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   // above provided code fragment with "await queryInterface._createTable(" goes here  },
   down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   await queryInterface.dropTable('User2s');
   }
   };
3. execute above migration
   npx sequelize-cli db:migrate
   Observe that it creates the User2s table with above CREATE TABLE sql
4. Create 'seed' file for User2
   npx sequelize-cli seed:generate --name init-user2
5. Manually update above created seed of User2 as (NOTE not specifying id value, for it to be auto assigned via default mechanism);

   'use strict';
   module.exports = {
   up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   await queryInterface.bulkInsert(
   {tableName: 'User2s', schema: 'exp15c'},
   [
   { firstName: 'ilker',  lastName: 'kiris',   email: 'ilker@gmail.com',  createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date() },
   { firstName: 'selcuk', lastName: 'gecer',   email: 'selcuk@gmail.com', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date() },
   { firstName: 'turhan', lastName: 'bozkurt', email: 'turhan@gmail.com', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date() }
   ], {}
   );
   },

   down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   await queryInterface.bulkDelete('User2s', null, {});
   }
   };
6. execute above seed for User2
   npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all
   NOTE above fail with
   ERROR: null value in column "id" of relation "User2s" violates not-null constraint
   because the generated CREATE TABLE sql is not really using defaultValue variable

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I am very surprised about lack of proper documentation, example and stackoverflow answers on this basic topic of using UUID as PK id. I am documenting answer in detail below so others don't suffer like me.

After many trials and errors, I found the solution;
Turns out, with PostgreSQL,

1. With PostgreSQL, by default only "plpgsql" extension is enabled.
   So, to use "uuid_generate_v1()", you need to enable "uuid-ossp" PostgreSQL extension via issuing:
   `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`
2. And in migration file need to use:

   `defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()')`

Here is the code snippet from migration file:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable(
      'Users', {
        id: {
          allowNull: false,
          defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v4()'),
          primaryKey: true,
          type: Sequelize.UUID
        },
        firstName: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        lastName: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        createdAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE
        },
        updatedAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE
        }
      }, {
        schema: process.env.DB_POSTGRESQL_SCHEMA_NAME
      });
    },
    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you clean the code to be readable and colonized thank you